# How to make code style in comment?

Tags: support, comments, new-users

I know How to do that in questions or answers.But how can I make codes a code-style in comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place backticks (`) around the code to have monospaced code in comments.

Comment: Example: `Yo estoy bediendo la refresco y comiendo el pan`

Comment: `If you wanted to be annoying, you could make your entire comment mono-spaced. It would also give you 2 more characters towards the minimum character limit.`

Comment: ¿bediendo? No entiendo.

Comment: code as  `print 'code style like this'`